# How to start node.js app with pm2 in cluster mode?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cluster-computing, pm2

We are trying to start our app with pm2 0.12.8 on ubuntu 14.04 with octa core proccessor. The read me on the git hub has a very straight forward command for running node app in cluster mode.

**# Cluster mode**

```
$ pm2 start app.js -i 0        **# Will start maximum processes with LB depending on available CPUs**
$ pm2 start app.js -i max      **# Same as above, but deprecated yet.**
```

But the above command are not working for us. When we try to run these commands only one instance is listed by pm2.

Why?
Any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

have you tried starting a fixed number of processes? i.e.

```
pm2 start app.js -i 2 //should start two instances.
```

what does "pm2 monit" show you?

also try

```
pm2 stop all
pm2 delete all
```

and then

```
pm2 start app.js -i 0
```

if you stop a process in pm2 it still reserves one cpu for it even if its not running. you should allways use pm2 delete

Comment: like pm2 start app.js -- test -i 2

Comment: use a JSON App declaration to pass parameters
https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/master/ADVANCED_README.md#a10

Comment: The delete all is key. PM2 will remember the last time you started the app in fork mode so unless you delete it it will restart as fork.

Comment: pm2 start app.js -i max =

Start with maximum instance

Comment: @HolgerWill pm2 monit for me displays blank screen regardless of what i attempt. any clues?

Answer (score 12):

Since you are looking to use a process file to manage your pm2, the process file should look similar to this:

```
    // ecosystem.js
    {
    "apps" : [{
      "name"      : "API",
      "script"    : "server.js",// name of the startup file
      "instances" : 4,          // number of workers you want to run
      "exec_mode" : "cluster",  // to turn on cluster mode; defaults to 'fork' mode 
      "env": {
        "PORT"      : "9090" // the port on which the app should listen
      }
      // for more options refer : http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#process-file
    }]
    }
```

Run this app using the following command to start and stop respectively:

```
$ pm2 start ecosystem.js
$ pm2 stop ecosystem.js
```

Answer (score 8):

For fresh process

```
pm2 start app.js --name "my-node-app" -i 2 // to create 2 process
```

To make existing running process. You have to stop and delete the current running process, if it was fork mode. Then only it can create cluster mode.

```
pm2 stop my-node-app
pm2 delete my-node-app
pm2 start app.js --name "my-node-app" -i 2 // to create 2 process
```

Comment: In my case using the --name flag forces pm2 to use cluster mode

Answer (score 1):

I think you might ever start this project with normal mode (fork_mode), so you should delete all process list before change to cluster mode, since pm2 will memorise ur start options

```
pm2 delete all
pm2 start app.js -i [NUMBER_OF_INSTANCE|max]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the best information here : [pm2 cluster mode](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

To enable the cluster mode, just pass the -i option:

```
pm2 start app.js -i max
```

max means that PM2 will auto detect the number of available CPUs and run as many processes as possible

Or via a js/yaml/json file:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    script    : "api.js",
    instances : "max",
    exec_mode : "cluster"
  }]
}
```

NOTE: you need to set the exec_mode to cluster so PM2 know you want to load balance between each instances, by default it will not

Then to start the Process File:

pm2 start processes.json
The -i or instances option can be:

0/max to spread the app across all CPUs

-1 to spread the app across all CPUs - 1

number to spread the app across number CPUs.